# Filtering data of the data frame. Failed. Runtime error

Tags: r

> Here is the task: Using the logical vector **air_fltr**, pick the values of Acid.Conc. (from defined data frame stackloss), for which Air.Flow < 60.
>   The chosen values themselves are to be saved in variable **acid_subset**, the table of unique values frequences of acid concentrations for the chosen data is to be saved in variable **acid_concs**.
>
> Here is my solution:

```
air_fltr <- stackloss[stackloss$'Air.Flow'<60, ]
acid_subset <- air_fltr[ , 3]
acid_concs <- table(acid_subset)
```

> There is an error that I have failed to deal with.

```
Failed. Runtime error
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
Calls: [ -> [.data.frame
Execution halted
```

> What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please add some example dataset that produces the error then people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do :

1) creating a logical vector

```
air_fltr <- stackloss$`Air.Flow` < 60
```

2) picking the values

```
acid_subset <- stackloss[air_fltr, 3]
```

3) Create table.

```
table(acid_subset)
```

Comment: I have tried it. But the problem remains. It is tested with stdin → stdout.

Comment: @Viking553 Can you please add data with `dput(head(air_fltr))` ?

Comment: > dput(head(air_fltr))
c(80, 80, 75, 62, 62, 62)

Comment: So basically do you need `table(air_fltr)` ?

Comment: The task is to be done in three steps: 1) air_fltr <- stackloss[stackloss$'Air.Flow'<60, ] (creating a logical vector); 2) acid_subset <- air_fltr[ , 3] (picking the values); 3) then the data is to be used to build a table of frequences of values.

Comment: @Viking553 See updated answer if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
stackloss %>%
   filter(`Air.Flow` < 60) %>%
   select(3) %>%
   count(!! rlang::sym(names(.)))
```